# jquery function in function variable not recognized

Tags: function, variables, click, jquery

I have this two functions (function in function) but the second one is not firing because it seems that indxc can not catch the id from the parent function.

```
$(".guddi").live('click',function(){
    $("#licolor").show();
    var indx = $(this).attr("id");
    if (indx < 0) {
    $('#color').css('display','none');
    return;
    }
    var item = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer risch"><span>Choose color</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">';
    for (g=0; g < menu[indx].color.length; g++){
    item += '<li><span class="pointer search_link" searchkey="'+ leString +' xdz'+ menu[indx].wert + ' xdz'+ menu[indx].color[g].farbe +'" id="'+[g]+'">' + menu[indx].color[g].farbe + '</span></li>';
    }

    $("#color").html(item+'</ul>').fadeIn();
    $("#color").menuFlip();

    $(".risch").live('click',function(){
        $("#liqual").show();
        var indxc = $(this).attr("id");
        if (indxc < 0) {
        $('#qual').css('display','none');
        return;
        }
        var item2 = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>Choose quality</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">';
        for (i=0; i < menu[indx].color[indxc].quality.length; i++){
        item2 += '<li><span class="pointer search_link" searchkey="'+ leString +' xdz'+ menu[indx].color[indxc].quality[i].wert +'">' + menu[indx].color[indxc].quality[i].wert + '</span></li>';
        }

        $("#qual").html(item2+'</ul>').fadeIn();
        $("#qual").menuFlip();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you fiddle this so me could get what you intend to do ? This way we could give you the best answer ... note that live method is deprecated since 1.7 and has been removed as of jQ 1.9 `:)`

Comment: this is a bit hard to fiddle. you can check live on http://stores.ebay.co.uk/INTENT24#

Comment: This is the HTML part: <div id="navigBoxLeft"> <h2 class="persNavigation sizeFinder">Finder</h2> <div class="clear" style="height: 1px;"> </div> <ul> <li class="mto_cat_item"><span class="pointer search_link noar" searchkey="xdzPartyzelte_Festzelte" style="cursor:pointer; padding: 3px 10px; width: 90%;">Marquees Pavilions</span></li> <li class="mto_cat_item"><span class="pointer search_link noar" searchkey="xdzXXL_Zelte" style="cursor:pointer; padding: 3px 10px; width: 90%;">Oversize tents</span></li> <li class="mto_cat_item" style="display:none;" id="lisize"> <div class="fn_menu_box" id="size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`live()` is depreciated in Jquery , so you can use `on()` instead, e.g.

and also try to `alert` inside second function.

```
$(".risch").on('click',function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: If alert says nothing is means you are not getting id attribute inside second function as you want.

Comment: correct. and this my problem...i have no solution yet. so i asked you guys because the community knowledge is much bigger than mine.

Comment: Where is your .risch declared ?

Comment: risch is dynamically generated by clicking the .guddi function

Comment: check var item = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer risch"><span>Choose color</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">'; where is attribute id ?

Comment: What output you want for $(this).attr("id") this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this fashion:

```
$(document).on('click', ".guddi", function(){
   // all the stuff but not the second elem clik event
});
```

put this outside and do this way:

```
$(document).on('click', ".risch", function(){
   // all stuff related to this event.
});
```

You need an `event delegation` to the `closest existing parent`. In you code it is hard to get so that's why i delegated to `document` it self because this is the parent of all elems in the page.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the click function from inside a function and write it outside and that should work..`live` is deprecated so I am using `on`..

**problem** in yours was.. you had click event inside click event.. so to fire `.risch` click event you had to click to `.guddi` which in turn is not possible since you cannot have two clicks at once... keeping it separately.. now document can find each click event and fire it correspondingly... so it works

```
$(".guddi").on('click',function(){
  $("#licolor").show();
  var indx = $(this).attr("id");
  if (indx < 0) {
   $('#color').css('display','none');
   return;
  }
  var item = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer risch"><span>Choose color</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">';
  for (g=0; g < menu[indx].color.length; g++){
     item += '<li><span class="pointer search_link" searchkey="'+ leString +' xdz'+ menu[indx].wert + ' xdz'+ menu[indx].color[g].farbe +'" id="'+[g]+'">' + menu[indx].color[g].farbe + '</span></li>';
  }

  $("#color").html(item+'</ul>').fadeIn();
  $("#color").menuFlip();
});

$(".risch").on('click',function(){
    $("#liqual").show();
    var indxc = $(this).attr("id");
    if (indxc < 0) {
      $('#qual').css('display','none');
      return;
    }
    var item2 = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>Choose quality</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">';
    for (i=0; i < menu[indx].color[indxc].quality.length; i++){
       item2 += '<li><span class="pointer search_link" searchkey="'+ leString +' xdz'+ menu[indx].color[indxc].quality[i].wert +'">' + menu[indx].color[indxc].quality[i].wert + '</span></li>';
    }

    $("#qual").html(item2+'</ul>').fadeIn();
    $("#qual").menuFlip();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. thank you @Devang Rathod...this was the master-hint :)

```
var item = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer risch"><span>Choose color</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">';
 for (g=0; g < menu[indx].color.length; g++){
 item += '<li><span class="pointer search_link" searchkey="'+ leString +' xdz'+ menu[indx].wert + ' xdz'+ menu[indx].color[g].farbe +'" id="'+[g]+'">' + menu[indx].color[g].farbe + '</span></li>';
```

}

changed to this

```
var item = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>Choose color</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">';
  for (g=0; g < menu[indx].color.length; g++){
     item += '<li><span class="pointer search_link risch" searchkey="'+ leString +' xdz'+ menu[indx].wert + ' xdz'+ menu[indx].color[g].farbe +'" id="'+[g]+'">' + menu[indx].color[g].farbe + '</span></li>';
  }
```

the .risch was in the wrong HTML element